# Render Firebase JSON object react

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

[image: Firebase JSON console.log()]

I have fetched some data from firebase like so:

```
getUserData = () => {
    database
      .ref('orders/')
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;

        if (exists) {
            let data = snapshot.val();
            console.log("DATA IS: ", data);             
        }
    });
}
```

The image shows the console log. I am trying to render everything on a table in react. I'm having trouble iterating through the data. Do I need to convert it into an array first?

I am looking to render everything from the item_id, displayName, email, all order info

Answer (score 0):

First You need to convert into array and then you can use map for retrieve data.
For example:
if data is in array form then you can mapping of objects.
I hope it will helps you.

```
data.map((detail)=>{
console.log(detail.email);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from function,

```
function getUserData = () => {
    database
      .ref('orders/')
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;

        if (exists) {
            let data = snapshot.val();
            //console.log("DATA IS: ", data);   
            return data;
        }
    });
}


var data = getUserData();

data.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(data.email);
    console.log(data.img);
    console.log(data.name);
    console.log(data.section);
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

New javascript provide Object.values().SO, you convert your data into array like below and use it.

```
getUserData = () => {
        database
          .ref('orders/')
          .once('value')
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            const exists = snapshot.val() !== null;

            if (exists) {
                let data = snapshot.val();
                console.log("DATA IS: ", data);        
                //use Object.values(data)
                const dataArray = Object.values(data);
                //now you can map your dataArray 

            }
        });
    }
```